# Cannot call pointer to member function from static method

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I am having difficulty calling a pointer to a member function on an object that was cast from `void*`.  See below example:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int pointTo)
    {
        if (pointTo == 1)
            function = &Test::Function1;
        else
            function = &Test::Function2;
    }

    static void CallIt(void* cStyle)
    {
        Test* t(static_cast<Test*>(cStyle));
        (t->*function)();// error C2568: '->*': unable to resolve function overload
    }

    void CallIt()
    {
        (this->*function)();// Works just fine
    }

private:
    typedef void (Test::*ptrToMemberFunc)();

    ptrToMemberFunc function;

    void Function1()
    {
        std::cout << "Function 1" << std::endl;
    }

    void Function2()
    {
        std::cout << "Function 2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t1(1);
    Test t2(2);

    Test::CallIt(static_cast<void*>(&t1));
    Test::CallIt(static_cast<void*>(&t2));

    t1.CallIt();
    t2.CallIt();

    return 0;
}
```

What happens when the object is cast to `void*` and back?  Why can I no longer call the pointer to member function?

EDIT:

Modifying `CallIt()` as follows allows the program to compile, but I'm still curious as to why the original didn't work.

```
static void CallIt(void* cStyle)
{
    Test* t(static_cast<Test*>(cStyle));
    Test::ptrToMemberFunc pf(t->function);
    (t->*pf)();
}
```

Comment: that's funny that I just wrote exactly same code in wandbox, down to identificatiors. Tuple_cat's answer explains this. Basicly you have  to link object and callable, so one indirection operator is not enough. Some compilers give more  understandable  error messages, like they tell you that you can call only a static member this way - a hint that you didn't had  a this pointer for them

Comment: Regarding your edit, I just think the look of operator `->*` is throwing you off. Consider it was just a regular function named `call_with_this`, that took a pointer to an object and a member function. Then your original not-working call was `call_with_this(t, function);`. Here it just so happens the name `function` is a non-static member of the `Test` class, but it has nothing to do with `t`. And because you're in a static function, there is no `this` to look in to resolve the name `function`. Once you ask for `t->function`, you have an actual value with an accessible name.

Comment: @GManNickG That's exactly it.  Now that I see the solution, I get it, but I didn't realize what the `->*` operator was actually doing (I was reading it as `(t->(*function))`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
main.cpp:17:14: error: invalid use of member 'function' in static member function
        (t->*function)();// error C2568: '->*': unable to resolve function overload
             ^~~~~~~~
```

`function` is a non-static data member, so you cannot access it from a static function.

If you want to refer to `t`'s `function`, you can do it like so:

```
        (t->*(t->function))();
```

Comment: That is the same reason why he is forced to write  `(this->*function)()` in non-static member, the innermost indirection operator "gets" value of pointer, while outmost allows call in reference to the object